# framework is not found when i am clicking on' +' on linked framework & libraries

Tags: iphone, frameworks

i am adding an framework is not found when i am clicking on' +' on linked framework & libraries i want to add an audio toolkit framework and core audio how can i add these two frameworks.as they are not in the libraries please help me.

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
```

Comment: your problem solve or not?

Comment: If you don't find these framework in your XCode then give me your mail id I will send you these framework then add these framework manually in XCode....

Comment: @vishal hey thankyou but i have deleted those framework instead of removing their reference..now its fine...issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that framework is available at path `../Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS(version).sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/` else you have to reinstall the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Please check like this 
project setting - > Build phases - >Link binary with libraries

[image]

and make sure this frame works are added regarding AV foundation work.

[image]